# problems with PHP and ADODB library and SQL server

Tags: php, adodb

I have a PHP function using ADODB library. My query is simple, select distinct SessID from 'table'.

When I iterate, I keep getting the following error:
    Notice: Undefined index: SessID in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\conference\AbstractSearchDAO.php on line 116

Here is the code:

public function searchAbstracts($name,$title){

```
    /**,$dayArray,$sessionTypeArray, $abstractTypeArray,$groupBy*/

    $sql_abstract_session_ids = "select distinct SessID from ABSTRACT where ";
    if($name!=null && $title!=null){
        $sql_abstract_session_ids .= "FALastName like "."'%".$name."%' or AbstractTitle like "."'%".$title."%'";    
    }elseif($name!=null && $title==null){
        $sql_abstract_session_ids .= "FALastName like "."'%".$name."%'";
    }elseif($name==null && $title!=null){
        $sql_abstract_session_ids .= "AbstractTitle like "."'%".$title."%'";
    }elseif($name==null && $title==null){
        $sql_abstract_session_ids = "select distinct SessID from ABSTRACT";
    }

    $connect = new ATSDataSourceLocator();
    $conn = $connect->connectConference2011();

    echo $sql_abstract_session_ids;


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //let's get the session ids from the abstract table.
    //we can then match them with another search on the session table (where SessID in (...abstract_session_ids....)
    $ADODB_FETCH_MODE = ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC;
    $rs = $conn->Execute($sql_abstract_session_ids);
    if($rs==false) die('failed');



    $sql_session_data = "select * from SESSION where SessID in (";

    $count = $rs->RecordCount();

    $myCount = 0;





    while(!$rs->EOF){

        $sql_session_data.="'".$rs->fields['SessID']."'";

        if($myCount<($count-1)){
            $sql_session_data.=",";
        }

        $myCount++;

        $rs->MoveNext();

    }

    $sql_session_data.=")";
    //$conn->Close();

    echo $sql_session_data;

}
```

Whenever I try to Iterate and get the field 'SessID' It fails.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check out how `ADODB_ASSOC_CASE` is defined and compare that value to the [ADODB manual](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#adodb_assoc_case).  If you're not setting it explicitly, it should be defaulted to `2`, which means your capitalization in your script has to match exactly the capitalization in the table.  Also, note that this must be `define`'d **before** you include `adodb.inc.php`.  And lastly, double- and triple-check that the field is definitely `SessID` in your `ABSTRACT` table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried $rs->fields('SessID') in your iteration - i.e. replace the square brackets with round?  Or, for example, keep the square brackets and use $rs->fields[0] (if it's the first field)?

With MySQL this isn't an issue, but it *will* throw an error if you use round instead of square with a field index, as opposed to name.  I don't have a SQL Server DB handy to test against.

Something in the back of my mind says this behaviour may also vary depending upon your ADODB_FETCH setting.  This, at least, does indeed appear to be driver-specific:

"If no fetch mode is predefined, the fetch mode defaults to ADODB_FETCH_DEFAULT. The behaviour of this default mode varies from driver to driver, so do not rely on ADODB_FETCH_DEFAULT. For portability, we recommend sticking to ADODB_FETCH_NUM or ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC. Many drivers do not support ADODB_FETCH_BOTH."